# Drupal 9 - Code modification doesn't take effect

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-9

I am trying to debug some code on my `Drupal 9` application.

For example, at the file `web/index.php`, I try to add `die('Was here')`

```
<?php 

    use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

    $autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';

    //My code is here
    die('Was here');

    $kernel = new DrupalKernel('prod', $autoloader);

    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $response = $kernel->handle($request);
    $response->send();
    $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

At first, I got the result on my browser. Next I delete this `die` function, and when i refresh my browser, I get the same as before as if I didn't change the code

After some minutes, the expected result is shown in my browser. So weird

So I am wondering why is Drupal isn't taking that code change into account.

Btw, I run the command `drush cr` but it didn't change anything

Comment: Maybe your site is also cached on some other level? BTW, isn't it only "drush cr", not "drush -cr"?

Comment: I actually don't know, this is why I posted here. About the command I mistyped it. it's like you said `drush cr`

Comment: @beta-developper , I have tested new installed Drupal 9.1 in my WAMP env and it works without any issue. You may check the following 1. drupal cache setting 2. web server cache config 3. your browser cookie about cache. Have you tried the debugging with incognito (chrome) or private mode(FF) which ignore cookie and cache?

Comment: Does it makes any difference if you are logged in or not?

Comment: @John I am gonna deep check that

Comment: @MilanG Actually it doesn't make a difference

Comment: Is any kind of file sync involved here (usually when using docker, vm's etc)?

Comment: You might be hitting opcache. Have you tried restarting your php-fpm service after the modification? If this makes your modification work everytime, check your php.ini setup (or additional .ini files loaded for php). In development, I always set `opcache.enable=0` to avoid this. In production, you better keep opcache enabled, of course, for better performance.

Comment: @HéctorPaúlCervera-García exactly it was opcache who caused this behavior. Disabling it solved the problem.

Comment: @JimPanse No there was no sync involved. The problem was caused by OpCache who was enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like PHP OpCode Cache.
You can see if its enabled or not in the Drupal status report under "PHP OPcode caching".
There's a page on on disabling Drupal Caching [here][1] which includes a section on opcache.
I believe to disable opcache you can add an entry to your php.ini file.

```
opcache.enable=0
```

Be sure to restart relevant services like php-fpm. And verify it was effective in the Drupal status report.
[1]: https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914

Comment: I enabled OpCache as Drupal recommend it. But I think there is no need for it in a development environment. Thank you @dabonde